# Python pandas lambda compare two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns of currencies in a, b;

There are some cells that are empty in both columns.

I am hoping to create a third column c to identified the following logic:

```
if a == b then display 'same'
elif a == None then display 'a missing'
elif b == None then display 'b missing'
elif a == None and b == None then display 'all missing'
else 'diff currency'.
```

These are my codes below. It just return 'same' or 'diff currency', nothing in between.

Please shed some lights on my syntax or logic flaws here. Thank you so much!

```
import pandas as pd

# list of currencies
a = list(('USD USD CAD nan JMD nan HKD CAD').split())

b = list(('USD CAD RMB HKD nan nan USD EUR').split())


# df
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b)), columns=['a', 'b'])

df = df.replace('nan', '')


df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Same' if x['a'] == x['b'] 
                   else ('a missing' if x['a']==None
                         else ('b missing' if x['b']==None 
                         else ('a & b missing' if x['a']==None and x['b']==None
                         else 'diff currency'))), axis=1)
```

Comment: Make a real function instead of trying to squeeze it into a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# list of currencies
a = list(('USD USD CAD nan JMD nan HKD CAD').split())

b = list(('USD CAD RMB HKD nan nan USD EUR').split())

# df
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b)), columns=['a', 'b'])

# change string `nan` into actual NaN values
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)

condlist = [df.a == df.b, df.isna().all(axis=1), df.a.isna(), df.b.isna()]
choicelist = ['same', 'all missing', 'a missing', 'b missing']

df['c'] = np.select(condlist,choicelist,default='diff currency')
print(df)

     a    b              c
0  USD  USD           same
1  USD  CAD  diff currency
2  CAD  RMB  diff currency
3  NaN  HKD      a missing
4  JMD  NaN      b missing
5  NaN  NaN    all missing
6  HKD  USD  diff currency
7  CAD  EUR  diff currency
```

Comment: oh wow. mind blown! thank you so much! definitely keep this trick in my notes moving forward.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answers offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question (and consider upvoting).

Comment: accepted and closed. i'd love to upvote which i did. but unfortunately i don't have 15 reputations yet. i truly appreciated your knowledge in this. thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you learn how to use the vectorized functions. They are both idiomatic pandas and extremely fast. Use `np.select`:

```py
a = df["a"]
b = df["b"]
df["c"] = np.select(
    [a.isna() & b.isna(), a.isna(), b.isna(), np.isclose(a, b)],
    ["all missing", "a missing", "b missing", "same"],
    "diff currency",
)
```

Comment: thank you so much! really appreciated your suggestion!